# wavelet analysis transforms

Tags: signal-processing, wavelet, wavelet-transform

Design a 4-stage wavelet analysis transforms code capable of transforming a 1D Voice/Speech signal to various lowpass and highpass filter components. Use the Haar, Daubechies-4, Morlet, Cauchy and Shannon wavelets?

Comment: What are you after? The code which does it?

Comment: If this is a homework exercise please explicitly state so.